# SSRS - Interactive Sorting with LookupSet Expression

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that I need to add an interactive sorting, but the column that I need to add the sorting has a LookUpSet `=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Format(Fields!cntSelfService.Value, "###,#######0"), "ExecutionCount"))` expression that has a hyperlink to another report. When the interactive sort is clicked the numbers are not sorting correctly.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the FORMAT function is converting the `cntSelfService` field to a string and then it is sorted as a string by characters instead of number (where "89" is less that "9").

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Format(Fields!cntSelfService.Value, "###,#######0"), "ExecutionCount"))
```

Can you remove the FORMAT and use the Text Box's FORMAT **Property** to format the data like you want?

```
=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!cntSelfService.Value, "ExecutionCount"))
```

[image]

I don't think there's another way since you're using Interactive sorting.

Now that I look at it again, do you ever get more than 1 record with the LookUpSet? If so both your and my expression would fail. If not, you could just use LookUp and not use JOIN.

Comment: No. It is 1 record per Report. I will try to remove the format.

Comment: Nope.  Removing the format syntax has no change. it works on other fields that does not have an expression.